# How to make `this` point to the outer class where the inner class has the same method name

Tags: java

Let's say I have the following code:

```
abstract class MyStream
{
    public abstract Iterable<Integer> getIterable();

    public MyStream append(final int i)
    {
        return new MyStream()
        {
            @Override
            public Iterable<Integer> getIterable()
            {
                return cons(/*outer class's*/getIterable(), i);
            }
        };
    }

    public static Iterable<Integer> cons(Iterable<Integer> iter, int i) { /* implementation */ }
}
```

How can I reference `getIterable` of the outer class from the inner class with the same name?

`MyStream.this` should point to the inner class here, right? How to show an outer class with the same name?

Comment: You could use a local variable within the append method and set this to it

Comment: @RichardTingle that's my current solution, but it's not elegant. i wonder if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you call `MyStream.this` from the anonymous class it will point to the outer class so the code below should work as you expect:

```
return const(MyStream.this.getIterable(), i);
```

(if it did not you would get a StackOverflowError).

The reason why it works is that [an anonymous class ***is*** an inner class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.5-130).

---

Simplified example that prints `outer 1`:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
  MyClass c = new MyClass() {
    @Override public String get() { return "outer"; }
  };
  System.out.println(c.append(1).get());
}

static abstract class MyClass {
  public abstract String get();

  public MyClass append(final int i) {
    return new MyClass() {
      @Override public String get() {
        return cons(MyClass.this.get(), i);
      }
    };
  }

  public static String cons(String iter, int i) { return iter + " " + i; }
}
```

Comment: Did you try this?  I'd be surprised if it worked, because the anonymous class being instantiated is not an inner class of `MyStream`.

Comment: OK, fair enough then.  I guess I'm wrong.  And surprised.

Answer (score 1):

`MyStream.this` does not point to the inner class. The inner class is *anonymous*. It may confuse you because you used `new MyStream() {...}`, but in fact it's a new inner class, which has an internal name, and the `new MyStream() {...}` syntax simply serves to replace the `SomeClass extends MyStream` syntax.

It is worth noting that the inner class both *extends* `MyClass` and is *nested* in it. This means that both `super` and `MyClass.this` exist and are `MyClass` references, but they are two distinct object instances. `super` points to the inner class instance itself, but looks at it as if it was `MyClass`, while `MyClass.this` is the enclosing object.